# Understanding a lemma in Milne's etale cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, etale-cohomology

I am reading chapter VI of J. Milne's book, Etale Cohomology. This chapter begins with cohomological dimensions: if $X$ is a finitely generated scheme over a separably closed field $k$, then (étale) cohomological dimension of $X$ is at most $2\dim(X)$. The proof (theorem 1.1 in the book) reduces to the case when $X$ is integral and sheaves of the form $g_{*}\mathcal{F}$ where $g: \eta \longrightarrow X$ is the generic point of $X$ and $\mathcal{F}$ a torsion sheaf on $\eta$.

**Lemma 1.2**. *The sheaf $R^j g_*\mathcal{F}$ has support in dimension $\leq n - j$*.

*Proof*. Let $x \in X$, and $A= \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{sh}$ (strict Henselization of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$), let $A_1,...,A_r$ be quotients of $A$ by minimal prime ideals whose fields of fractions are $K_1,...,K_r$.

**First question**. Why do we have:
$$(R^j g_*\mathcal{F})_{\overline{x}} = \bigoplus H^j(K_r,\mathcal{F}_{\mid K_r})$$
I know that we can compute the LHS as
$$(R^j g_*\mathcal{F})_{\overline{x}} = H^j(\eta \times_X \mathrm{Spec}(A), \mathcal{F})$$ so the above may follows once we know that
$$\eta \times_X \mathrm{Spec}(A) = \coprod \mathrm{Spec}(K_r)$$
**Second question**. Suppose that we have such a decomposition, we want to bound the cohomological dimension of those $K_r$, Milne claims that we can do that once the following is true

**Lemma 1.3**. *For any $x \in X$, there exists another $X'/k$ finitely generated and a closed point $x' \in X'$ such that $\mathcal{O}^{sh}_{X,x} \simeq \mathcal{O}^{sh}_{X',x'}$*.

I do not see why we need $x'$ to be closed here?

Comment: 1st question. The strict henselisation is flat so satisfies going down by 15.45.1 in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07QL and 10.41.1 in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HU. Combine this with 15.45.13 in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07QL to get what you want.

Comment: Hi Damian, are you implicitly saying that $\eta \times_X A$ is total ring of fractions of $A$ (assume $X$ affine if necessary)?